# How to pass a Javascript variable to apex output panel

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a javascript variable that retrieves the value from different visualforce page. I am able to retrieve the value on the current visualforce page it will be either true or false. i can see from console.log() that the value do exist on page. what i need is to use this JS (onlinecred) value in apex image for rendering the image if true or false.

**Sample Code:**

```
<script>
var onlinecred = parent.frames['Page_X'].getonlineidexists();
</script>
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:image url="{!$Resource.OnlineCredentials}" width="24" height="18"  rendered="onlinecred"/>
```

Comment: You can use action function to pass value from javascript to apex.

Comment: that's correct. But i dont need to pass it to any controller class. Just need to use it in the VF page to render the image.